# Can this equation be solved by radicals? $x^6+x^5+2x^4-2x^3-x^2+1=0$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, abelian-groups

Can this equation be solved by radicals? If it can be solved, what is the method? At least, I will resolve it myself if you specify reference or source.

> $$x^6+x^5+2x^4-2x^3-x^2+1=0$$

Comment: The Galois group is of order 72; hence solvable.

Comment: Which method We can solve this equation?

Comment: @i. m. soloveichik Which software are you using for getting the Galois group (or at least its size...) ?

Comment: @Jean Marie Maple16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because$$x^6+x^5+2x^4-2x^3-x^2+1=0\iff (x^3-1)^2+x^2(x^3-1)+2x^4=0$$ It follows solving as a quadratic in $x^3-1$
$$2(x^3-1)=-x^2\pm\sqrt{-7}x\iff2x^3+x^2\mp\sqrt{-7}x^2-2=0$$ so you can apply Cardano's formula.

Comment: [+1] Very clever ! But I wouldn't have phrased it as you do : I would have simply completed the square under the form  $[((x^3-1)+\tfrac12 x^2)^2-\tfrac14 x^4]+2x^4$ and then proceed as you do to 2 third degree equations.

Comment: Take care, there is a little flaw in your last equation(s) : they should be :$2x^3+(1\pm i\sqrt{7})x^2-2=0$ (no first degree term)

Comment: Thank you very much. I fall into slips every moment.

Comment: The two cubic equations giving the six roots come from $$(2x^3+(1-\sqrt{-7})x^2-2)(2x^3+(1+\sqrt{-7})x^2-2)=4(x^6+x^5+2x^4-2x^3-x^2+1)=0$$. With keen insight it could have been directly factor the given equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}$, $E=Q(a)$, then the given polynomial factors as $f=(x^3+ax^2-1)(x^3+\bar{a}x^2-1)$. It is easy to see that the cubic factors are irreducible over $E$ and that their discriminants are not squares in $E$. Hence the Galois group of $f$ over $E$ is $H=S_3\times S_3$ and that the Galois group $G$ of the original polynomial is the semidirect product extension of $H$ by $Z_2$ (complex conjugation). Thus the full Galois group $G$ is of order 72 and solvable. To obtain the roots we can use the the standard formulas for solving a cubic.